How do I ensure that AsyncTaskExecutor gracefully cleans up virtual threads before stopping an app?
I have a custom implementation of AsyncTaskExecutor which uses Virtual Threads to run tasks. I am using ThreadFactory here as I need to wrap the task to perform cross-cutting concerns.
As VTs are daemon threads, I think that these threads will keep running in the background for some time even after an application is stopped.
is there a way to ensure that all the virtual threads created using AsyncTaskExecutor get cleaned up before the application stops?
AsyncTaskExecutor:
public class VirtualThreadTaskExecutor implements AsyncTaskExecutor {
    private final ThreadFactory threadFactory;

    public VirtualThreadTaskExecutor() {
        this.threadFactory = Thread.ofVirtual().name("my-app-virtual-thread-", 0).factory();
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(@NotNull Runnable task) {
        var wrapped = MyTaskWrapper.wrap(task);
        threadFactory.newThread(wrapped).start();
    }

     ...
}

Bean:
@Bean
public AsyncTaskExecutor virtualThreadExecutor() {
    return new VirtualThreadTaskExecutor();
}

I believe the other option is to use SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor and setTaskTerminationTimeout which get called when close() method is called.

Can you also share what is wrong/challenging with setTaskTerminationTimeout in your case?

Your reasoning is odd. Why should the fact that virtual threads are daemon threads imply that they will keep running in the background longer than platform threads? Further, it’s not clear what you mean with “get cleaned up before the application stops”. What kind of cleanup do you have in mind?

Instead of defining a custom VirtualThreadTaskExecutor, what you can work around with is to make use of the TaskDecorator for dealing with your wrap implementation and at the same time making use of virtual threads with the SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor with setVirtualThreads configuration set as true. Along with this, as you pointed out the way to wait for task termination would be to set it explicitly using setTaskTerminationTimeout.
The @Bean for this would look like:
@Bean
public AsyncTaskExecutor virtualThreadTaskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    asyncTaskExecutor.setVirtualThreads(true); // virtual threads enabled
    asyncTaskExecutor.setTaskDecorator(MyTaskWrapper::wrap); // your custom wrapper
    asyncTaskExecutor.setThreadFactory(Thread.ofVirtual().name("my-app-virtual-thread-", 0).factory());
    asyncTaskExecutor.setTaskTerminationTimeout(5000); // ensure wait for task termination
    return asyncTaskExecutor;
}

Edit:

(ref: spring-boot-virtual-threads)With spring.threads.virtual.enabled set to true, the line of code setVirtualThreads(true) is implicitly taken care of impacting the behavior of methods annotated with @EnableAsync.

Ideally, Spring takes care of the underlying lifecycle of the Executor. But as much as I could test it out, you would have to mostly ensure that the task termination is considered during application shutdown for such a declaration by invoking its close() method via a hook such as PreDestroy explicitly.



setTaskTerminationTimeout will come into the picture only once the close() method is called on asyncTaskExecutor. Does that mean I should call close method in preDestroy lifecycle hook of the bean?

@GovindaSakhare updated the aspect in the answer, ideally should be taken care by spring implicitly, but as much as I could test (might be missing out something), you would have to be explicit in the invocation of close via a hook.
